# How to install Signal desktop without owning a smart phone and without google account

Tags: android

Is there any way to install the desktop version of Signal without having a physical smart phone and also without having to register a Google account?

I tried doing it with Anbox (android emulator), but since it does not have support for camera, I got stuck when I should scan the QR-code.

And yes, I'm aware that this will lead to that a lot of messages will have to wait until I come home because Signal will automatically use Signal for anyone who have it, and just use sms if they don't.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. If you just want to avoid google apps but are ok with using a smart phone, or vice versa, you can use parts of this guide.

You will need: A computer with a webcam and a cell phone

I also recommend: Software that can virtualize Ubuntu

1. From your main os, goto https://signal.org/sv/download/ to download and install the desktop version. It's available for Linux, Mac and Windows.
2. Start Signal desktop. It should show a QR code. Make sure that your webcam can see the code. If you solve this by having a separate movable webcam, multiple screens or printing the qr code on paper is up to you. But You have to be able to see the qr code in the web cam.
3. I installed a virtual machine (VM) with Ubuntu 20. This is not strictly necessary, but I had problems getting Genymotion working together with VirtualBox on my Debian system. And installing a VM just seemed so much easier than dealing with those problems.
4. If you decide to use a VM, make sure that you are able to get your webcam working in it. This was very simple in my case. I just added a USB device and chose the webcam.
5. In the Ubuntu VM (or main os if you did not use a VM), install VirtualBox. This is a requirement for the next step.
6. In the Ubuntu VM (or main os), install [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download/)
7. In Genymotion, create a phone with the template "Custom phone Android 5.1 API 22" with default settings. I'm sure it can work with others, but I had problems with Android 4 and 6 and the phone I mentioned is what I managed to do this with.
8. Fire up the phone you created. For some reason I had ENORMOUS performance problems with Genymotion. It was extremely slow and had an input lag of several seconds. I also had some network problems, but starting the phone in VirtualBox and waiting for an IP address before starting the phone in Genymotion seemed to help.
9. Make sure that the webcam gets passed to your phone. In Genymotion, just click the camera icon and choose source.
10. From the virtual phone, go to https://signal.org/android/apk/ and download the apk file to your phone. The current version is 4.59.11
11. Go to the download folder of your phone and click the file you downloaded. It will probably ask you to allow untrusted sources. Just do it.
12. You will need a cell phone to get the verification code. As far as I know, this is unavoidable. Enter your phone number to receive the code to complete the installation.
13. Now when Signal is installed, open settings in Signal, choose "linked devices" and then the + icon to add a new device.
14. Use your webcam to scan the QR code shown in Signal desktop.
15. DONE! Now you should be able to chat with people without the virtual phone. You can turn it off and just use the desktop app.

Note: I did this recently, and so far I have not found a way to add new contacts without the virtual phone, so you should probably keep it. There may also be other reasons to do so that I don't know of. I recommend keeping it. Delete it at your own risk. Other people that I have not chatted with seems to be able to contact me though.

Note2: If you don't have a webcam, there are ways to trick this. I suppose you could use the program webcamoid to create a loopback or something, but I have not tried it and don't know how to do it.